# Using a bot to react with regional indicator symbols in JS (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, emoji

I was wondering if anyone with experience using Discord.js knew of a way to get the bot to react with the discord regional indicator S symbol?
I can get the bot to react with any other emoji, whether is unicode or custom, but it's not possible to escape the symbol since it just outputs a normal s.
For reference, here is the symbol in question: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA7Aq.png
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this didn't work for you, it did for me
:regional_indicator_s:

If it still doesn't work, just copy this: